# print command with a comma?

Tags: python, printing, edit

I've been reading that adding a comma at the end of a print command lists all the outputted strings for a function horizontally instead of vertically. But somehow my formatting isn't letting me do this

```
def foo(Y):
...
...
print foo(Y),
```

This still gives me

```
a
b
c
```

instead of

```
a b c
```

EDIT: my particular function is iterative, on another function

```
def encode(Y):
    for i in range(0, len(Y), 2):
        encode_pair(Y[i], Y[i+1]),
```

Comment: Can you show the function code as well? We can understand better, what you are trying to print.

Comment: What does the trailing comma on `encode_pair(Y[i], Y[i+1]),` do? What does `encode_pair(Y[i], Y[i+1])` do?

Comment: You say your function outputs strings vertically, and the function returns nothing, so this print statement is not doing anything. Your problem lies inside the function.

Comment: I'm not sure what the comma does. encode_pair is a much longer funciton

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because you're handling strings, and have a `\n` character at the end of it or perhaps at the beginning. To be sure, that there is no beginning or tailing whitespace, use `strip()`. So:

```
print str(foo(Y)).strip()
```

This is under the assumption that your function *returns* something, otherwise, the above example will not work. If Y is global, and your function in fact changes a global variable:

```
for var in Y:
    print var,
```

Comment: Yes my function outputs a number of two-length strings vertically. Getting them on one line is the issue for me.

Comment: Does the solution work for you then?

Comment: @kevin Does the function *output* them or *return* them? If it really *outputs* them, then all you can do is capture its output and process it. But as long as you refrain from showing us what the function exactly does, we only can guess. If it is classified in any way, try to show us a similiar function.

Comment: no it seems to make no difference relative to print foo(Y)

Comment: @glglgl I could not have explained it better. hi5 bro! :D

Comment: @glglgl i believe its an ouput, but i'm not sure on the distinction. and yes collecting the outputs in the list would do the job as well

Comment: @kevin Does it have the keyword `return` anywhere?

Comment: no but it does have print commands

Answer (score 0):

The `foo` function must be returning a string with a line feed at the end. Try:

```
print foo(Y).rstrip(),
```

If you try this and you are getting a `NoneType` error *while still seeing output*, then the printing must be happening inside your function and not with this `print` statement. The comma can only affect that particular statement, and not one inside your function. Search inside the function and remove the `print` Or put the comma there on the internal statement. Or `return` the value you would like to print and print it externally instead.

Comment: gives me the same vertical outputs with an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'" do i need set up another string for rstrip to work on?

Comment: @kevin Does your function return anything?

Comment: This will not work if he has a \n at the beginning of the string.

Comment: If you are getting the NoneType error, I think the printing must be happening inside your function and not with this print statement. It would not print the lines and then give one error.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac clearly so but seems unlikely. I was going to specify `.strip('\n')` but wasn't sure of the OS and I don't like stripping blindly esp. from both ends because of tabs etc.

Comment: @beroe Yea, that would get rid of data _inside_ the string too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your function only prints. So you should modify it. If you cannot do so, you'll have to redirect `stdout` temporarily:

```
import cStringIO
import sys
buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

sys.stdout = buf
*do your printing calls*
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

output = buf.getvalue()
# This is now a string with all the output.

print output.replace('\n', ' ') # Output it with line breaks replaced with spaces.
```

If you do such things more often, you can do

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def redir_stdout(temptarget):
    import sys
    try:
        t = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = temptarget
        yield None
    finally:
        sys.stdout = t
```

and then

```
import cStringIO
buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

with redir_stdout(buf):
    *do your printing calls*

output = buf.getvalue()
# This is now a string with all the output.
```